# Set analysis syntax

Tags: qlikview

I'm just learning Qlikview and am struggling with the syntax for set analysis.  I have a dimension called OPEN_DT which is a date field.  For this little exercise I just want to have the expression count the records where the date is on or before 02/27/2014.  Step 2 will be to make the date dynamic but for now I'm at the "Hello, World" stage.

I've tried the following and what feels like 50 variations thereof...

```
COUNT({
    <
     OPEN_DT    = {"<{(= Date('2014-02-27', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))} "}
    >} MTTER_ID)
```

Can anyone help me sort this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
COUNT({
    <
     OPEN_DT = {"$(=Date(Date#('2014-02-27', 'YYYY-MM-DD')))"}
    >} MTTER_ID)
```

or with a variable (using calendar object):

```
COUNT({
    <
     OPEN_DT = {"$(=Date(vTheDate))"}
    >} MTTER_ID)
```